# Multiple test condition in a for loop logically associated with &&

Tags: c, for-loop, logical-operators

For Example:

```
for(j=0;t1&&t2&&t3;j++);
```

if t1 fails , will the for loop check for t2 and t3 or not?

Comment: See [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , if you have ( value && anything ) and value becomes false everything else is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

C will short-circuit expressions involving logical ANDs and ORs, so as soon as the result of the expression is known, evaluation will stop.  The given expression is:

```
t1 && t2 && t3
```

Since it's a logical AND operator, as soon as t1 is evaluated as false, evaluation of t2 and t3 will be skipped, since the overall result is known.

Answer (score 1):

In `for` loops and in all other situations where `&&` or `||` are used, evaluation proceeds left to right until the answer is known. At that point the evaluation stopped. This is known as *short circuiting*.

This is a very important feature, because it lets you "guard" subsequent expressions by inserting checks earlier on. For example,

```
if (ptr != 0 && ptr->property == 42) {
}
```

will not crash on `ptr == NULL` only because of short-circuiting. Had it not been for it, programmers would be forced to write much less pleasant

```
if (ptr != 0) {
    if (ptr->property == 42) {
    }
}
```

to avoid the crash.

Answer (score 1):

No, C and C++ guarantees "short circuiting" of conditions - meaning that the "tests" stop as soon as the condition can be determined - if something is false for `&&`, then the it's determined that it can never be `true`, and if something is `true` in an `||`, it can not be false.

This makes it safe to do something like:

```
if (ptr != NULL && ptr->x > 10) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [ISO 9899 C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (this one is a fairly recent draft version, but this particular paragraph has been present since the drafts of ANSI-C)

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the
>   evaluation of the first operand. **If the first operand compares equal
>   to 0, the second operand is not evaluated**.

Emphasis mine, so yes, a compiler must shortcircuit a logical and condition as soon as it encounters an operand that will cause it to return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Logically it doesn't need to since the first condition being false makes the entire statement false.  It's technically called a "short-circuit evaluation".  This is why you should't create `t2` and `t3` conditions that create side effects and assume they are happening every cycle of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

for(j=0; (t1 && t2) && (t2 && t3); j++); // should work

Misread the question. No it will not. C uses short circuit evaluation which means as soon as it's false, it's false.